# Running nextflow as a job vs. a pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nextflow

I'm new to nextflow. We would like to build our workflow using nextflow and have nextflow deploy the workflow to a large mulit-institution Kubernetes cluster that we use.

In this cluster we don't have admin permission, we have a namespace we work in. Also, pods in our cluster have limited resources, but jobs have unlimited resources.

In looking at [the documentation](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/kubernetes.html) for nextflow + kubernetes and it says that the workflow runs under a Kubernetes pod, which raises red flags for me because of the limitation on pods in our cluster.

Is there a way to execute nextflow workflows as a kubernetes jobs instead of a pod? What are my options in this area?

Comment: I don't quite see a reason why would you want to run the nextflow main pod as a job, as this is just a driver which is being used to deploy workflow jobs. Check what limits you have and what are the specs on the nextflow deployment.

Comment: Ah, if the pod it starts is just a driver that launches jobs then the limitations imposed on pods in our cluster is irrelevant (8 GB of ram and 4 CPUs would be plenty). It wasn't clear to me if that pod launches jobs or if it runs the workflow from within the pod itself. This is me being new to nextflow and not understanding how it's organized.

Comment: After running some tests we can see that Nextflow spawns a Kubernetes Pod to control the workflow as mentioned by @Spook, however, Nextflow then goes on to spin up a pod to execute the workflow step as well. So my question remains. The Pod used for control flow is fine, but the workflow steps themselves need to actually run in a Job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a new feature with nextflow 22.04. Quoting Ben Sherman's [nextflow k8s best practices](https://github.com/seqeralabs/nf-k8s-best-practices/blob/master/feature-evaluation.md) page:

> In Nextflow v22.04 and later, the `k8s` executor can be configured to use Jobs instead of Pods directly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a conversation on https://gitter.im/nextflow-io/nextflow, Nextflow cannot run a Job, it only supports spawning Pods. One pod is spawned for workflow control, and that Pod spawns pods for the individual tasks.

Comment: https://github.com/seqeralabs/nf-k8s-best-practices/blob/master/feature-evaluation.md
This source states: In Nextflow v22.04 and later, the k8s executor can be configured to use Jobs instead of Pods directly.

Comment: You could post that as an answer, it would be good to replace my answer now that it's changed. Thanks for this, it's timely news for me too!

Comment: I sure can, that's however all I found on k8s jobs.